# How to enforce type of exported function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I had this:

```
export const counterReducer: ActionReducer<number> = (state = 0, action: Action) => {
  const at = CounterActions;
  switch (action.type) {
    case at.incrementId:
      return state + 1;

    case at.decrementId:
      return state - 1;

    case at.resetId:
      return 0;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Unfortunately I had to rewrite it to `export function` form (without it AoT won't work):

```
export function counterReducer(state = 0, action: Action): number {
  const at = CounterActions;
  switch (action.type) {
    case at.incrementId:
      return state + 1;

    case at.decrementId:
      return state - 1;

    case at.resetId:
      return 0;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

As you can see I have lost the type of the whole function (`ActionReducer<number>`) which is not acceptable for me.

So the question is:
**How can be `export function` construct typed? How can I type it in the point of definition?**

Answer (score 0):

You can export a typed function like this:

```
export const counterReducer = (state = 0, action: Action) => ({
  ..
} as ActionReducer<number>);
```

Comment: I dont understand that. How can a TypeScript code not support Arrow functions?

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote explicitly `export function`. Also if you do it your way, if I am not mistaken, then TypeScript actually doesn't check the type of a function, you essentially override it to be `ActionReducer<number>` which is not what I want. I want TS to check that the function is of that type (this is what `: ActionReducer<number>` in "I had this:" part was doing).